# Connect to server without username or password using JSch

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, jsch

I'm using com.jcraft.jsch.JSch to create an SFTP connection.

My SSH keys are setup to where I'm able to SSH directly to the server without username or password.

```
ssh test_server
```

My public key is in an authorized_key file in `me@test_server:~/.ssh/` 
My SSH keys on my local machine are in `C:\cygwin\home\me\.ssh\` 
In addition, I also have a config file and a `known_hosts` file within this directory.

```
Host test_server
User user_name
HostName test_server.domain.com
ForwardAgent yes
```

To double-check, I made sure that my public key within `C:\cygwin\home\me\.ssh` is in the remote server's `authorized_keys` file.

I'm developing a GUI program that creates a file. With that file, I want to be able to store it on the remote server and place it within a folder there with SFTP. How am I able to do this?

Here's what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
    try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();

        String user = "";
        String host = "test_server";
        int port = 22;
        String privateKey = "C:/cygwin/home/me/.ssh/id_rsa";

        jsch.addIdentity(privateKey);
        System.out.println("identity added ");

        Session session = jsch.getSession("", host);
        System.out.println("session created.");

        session.connect();
        System.out.println("session connected.....");

        Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.setInputStream(System.in);
        channel.setOutputStream(System.out);
        channel.connect();
        System.out.println("shell channel connected....");

        ChannelSftp c = (ChannelSftp) channel;

        String fileName = "test.txt";
        c.put(fileName, "./in/");
        c.exit();
        System.out.println("done");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

I keep receiving a

> com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail error.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Additional Information (This might be useful... Unsure): 
When I open cmd, it takes me to `C:\Users\me`. 
But when I pass the "pwd" command, it prints out `/cygdrive/c/Users/me`.
I'm also open to any new libraries or perhaps just a better way to do this at all.  

Thank you so much!

Output for `ssh -v test_server`:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/me/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/me/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: /home/me/.ssh/config line 9: Applying options for wmpos1
debug1: Control socket "/home/me/.ssh/master-user_name@test_server:22" d
oes not exist
debug1: Connecting to test_server [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to test_server:22 as 'user_name'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64-etm@openssh.com comp
ression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64-etm@openssh.com comp
ression: none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:aV1o2Laclf7vRU2QOH+iWpuYYmy2
bokk8uQrVEaPL8k
debug1: Host 'test_server' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/me/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 151
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to test_server ([127.0.0.1]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
```

Comment: Show us an output of `ssh -v test_server`.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Hello! I have edited my post. Thank you so much for that! I will remember to attach this information if I have an issue like this again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you do not specify the username explicitly on `ssh` command-line does not mean, that no username is used.

The `ssh` by default uses a local username implicitly. JSch won't do that. You have to explicitly specify the username, even if it is the same as the local username.

Comment: Hello! You are correct. Thank you so much for your help!! Without the password, I was able to just enter the username used on test_server and bypass the password.